# I want to install Tesseract but ./configure fails

Tags: makefile, tesseract

This is the result from `./configure`:

```
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
Using git revision: 4.00.00alpha-358-g362b68e
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
./configure: line 4250: syntax error near unexpected token `-mavx,'
./configure: line 4250: `AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG(-mavx, avx=true, avx=false)'
```

This is the error that i get after running make:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Thus `sudo make install` doesnt work either.

Comment: Did you miss the part where `./configure` failed? Of course make will fail after that.

Comment: I saw that, i know make wouldn't work, that is exactly why i am here :) and seriously you just had to come and down vote this ... omg the community here is really judgemental.. two more people like you and i will be blocked from posting for the next four days, while I have a proof of concept to deliver this monday -_-

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. Below is what worked for me.

```
cd tesseract-3.05.00

./autogen.sh

PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig 

LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/include ./configure --with-extra-includes=/usr/local/include --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib

LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" make

make install

ldconfig
```

See below link for full script, that includes installing Leptonica and dependencies properly.
https://github.com/EisenVault/install-tesseract-redhat-centos/blob/master/install-tesseract.sh

Answer (score 1):

If configure fails with errors like these, then double check you have installed autoconf-archive and restart Tesseract installation process (./autogen.sh,./configure` ...)

And make sure that you have installed the latest version of laptonica, in my case it was [Laptonica-1.74](http://www.leptonica.org/source/leptonica-1.74.tar.gz), as it is required for the installation process.

[Reference to tesseract-ocr compiling](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling)